# How to pass Shiny browser timezone value from ui to server and readTzServer

Tags: r, shiny, server, timezone, logic

I have a modularized application with two "ui" functions (ui and readTzUi) and two "server" functions. For the application I want to read the timezone from a users browser with `readTzUi` (input#client_time_zone_international) and pass it on to `readTzServer`.

I have worked out a reproducable example of the app.

As you can see the `but_out` and `out` variable can be accessed through the `readTzServer`, but `input$client_time_zone_international` results in a `NULL` value.

Although `input$client_time_zone_international` is not available in `readTzServer`, it is available in `server` (The values of timezone are printed in the console for both `readTzServer` and `server`)

A few things that I have tried so far are:

1. pass `input$client_time_zone_international` from server to `readTzServer` with Callmodule
2. create a global variable of `input$client_time_zone_international`
3. capture `input$client_time_zone_international` in a variable from the `readTzUi` with `Shiny.setInputValue()`

All these options did not result in passing the `input$client_time_zone_international` value to `readTzServer`.

I hope someone can help me with this problem.

```
library(shiny)

readTzUi <- function(id, label = "readTz"){
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  fluidPage(
  tags$script('
  $(function() {
    $("input#client_time_zone_international").val(Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone)
  });    
'),
textInput("client_time_zone_international", "Time zone international", value = ""),
tags$br(),
actionButton(ns("button"), label = label),
verbatimTextOutput(ns("but_out")),
verbatimTextOutput(ns("out"))
)
  
}

readTzServer <- function(id){
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session){
      
      # This is where I need the timezone value
      observe(print(input$client_time_zone_international))
      
      count <- reactiveVal(0)
      observeEvent(input$button, {
        count(count() + 1)
      })
      output$but_out <- renderText({
        count()
      })
      count
      
      
                 observe({
                 output$out <- renderText({
                   "Hello"
                   })
                 })
               }
    )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  
 readTzUi("readtz1", "Counter#2")
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  readTzServer("readtz1")
  
  observe(
    print(input$client_time_zone_international)
    )
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is example how to get a timezone:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- basicPage(
  tags$script("$(document).on('shiny:sessioninitialized', function(event) {
                                        var n = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;
                                        Shiny.onInputChange('client_time', n);});")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observe({
    req(input$client_time)
    print(input$client_time)
  })
  
}

shinyApp (ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you for your time Pork Chop, but it doesn't completely answer my question. I also have the client time available in my app, but now I want client time available in the "readTzServer" as well. Any ideas how I pass the value to readTzServer?